# Bind scroll wheel to page up and down keys

Tags: linux, xorg, scroll-wheel

I have followed these https://www.linuxuprising.com/2019/11/how-to-bind-mouse-buttons-to-keyboard.html https://codepre.com/how-to-bind-mouse-buttons-to-keyboard-keys-or-commands-linux-uses-x11.html tutorials.

Using the `xev` program I know that scroll wheel up is button 4 and scroll wheel down is button 5 in Xorg and that page up is identified as 'Prior' and page down is identified is 'Next.'
Then I applied my changes with: `xbindkeys -p`.

However, the scroll wheel does not do anything at all.

Comment: Thanks for listing what you've tried. In the two tutorials you've linked I don't see a reference to `xbindkeys -p` at all, nor do I see it in the [manual](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xbindkeys). What should that command do? Also, can you [edit] your question to include what's in your `~/.xbindkeysrc` file?

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke, sorry but I removed the file and the program from my computer so that the scroll wheel would work.